# Convert three rows values into columns, NOT as comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have table structure like

```
select catalog_item_id,metal_type,metal_color 
from catalog_item_castings 
where catalog_Item_Id =465173
```

It returns output as:

[image]

And I want output as:

[image]

And I want to insert this data into new temp table in SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the number of castings always the same (`3`) ?

Comment: You need to look into pivoting.

Comment: Hi @Sander, No, number of castings not same always. They can different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is an option:

```
SELECT
   catalog_item_id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN CONCAT(metal_type, '/', metal_color) END) AS Casting_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN CONCAT(metal_type, '/', metal_color) END) AS Casting_2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN CONCAT(metal_type, '/', metal_color) END) AS Casting_3
FROM (
   SELECT 
      catalog_item_id, metal_type, metal_color, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
   FROM (VALUES
      (465173, 'na', 'METALCOLOR'),
      (465173, 'na', 'METAL-001'),
      (465173, 'na', 'na')
   ) catalog_item_castings (catalog_item_id, metal_type, metal_color) 
   WHERE catalog_Item_Id = 465173
) t   
GROUP BY catalog_item_id
-- or if you have more than three rows per [catalog_item_id]
-- GROUP BY catalog_item_id, (rn - 1) / 3
```

Result:

```
catalog_item_id Casting_1     Casting_2    Casting_3
-------------------------------------------------
465173          na/METALCOLOR na/METAL-001 na/na
```

Comment: Hi @Zhorov , thanks but the values 'na' and 'METAL COLOR' . . . . are not fixed.

Comment: @Dev, than you need a dynamic pivoting, but why the question is `Convert three rows values into columns, ...`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Aggregation within a Dynamic Pivot Statement in order to include all distinct combinations of the columns `[metal_type]` and `[metal_color]`, even different values for combinations are inserted in the future :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN [dr]=',dr,
                                         ' THEN CONCAT([metal_type],''/'',[metal_color]) END) AS [Casting_',dr,']'),',') 
                           WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY dr )
                  FROM 
                  ( 
                   SELECT DISTINCT 
                          DENSE_RANK() OVER 
                          (PARTITION BY [catalog_item_id]
                               ORDER BY CONCAT([metal_type],[metal_color])) AS dr
                     FROM [catalog_item_castings] ) c);

SET  @query = 
 'SELECT [catalog_item_id],'+ @cols + 
 ' FROM 
  (
   SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER 
           ( PARTITION BY [catalog_item_id] 
                 ORDER BY CONCAT([metal_type], [metal_color]) ) AS dr
     FROM [catalog_item_castings]
  ) c
 GROUP BY [catalog_item_id]';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a62982c5111d48f19879ec3a7797422c)</kbd>